# helpers definition with `helper_method` in rails 5 api mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Writing Rails applications I used to not have any instance variable in the views, instead I define `helper_method`s on the controller. Those methods will be used by the controller and the views the same way. This makes my code clean. Now with the `api` mode in Rails 5, I can't do that anymore, the `helper_method` is not there. The use of variables in the views is one of the things that I hate the most.

for example

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::API
   helper_method :products, :current_user

   private

   def products
     @products ||= current_user.products
   end

   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
   end
end
```

in the `index.json.jbuilder` view I'd like to use it this way.

```
 json.products products do |product|
    json.name product.name
    json.price product.price
    # and so on
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested this but you can try to add `AbstractController::Helpers` module in your controller before `helper_method`

`include AbstractController::Helpers`

The source code of `helper_method` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb